# How can I speed up the processing of my Romanian short-stay visa at the Romanian consulate in New York?

Tags: visas, romania, vacations, eastern-europe

I am a US permanent resident planning to go to Romania at the end of December. I was invited by my friend who I will be staying with there during the course of January.

However, my citizenship places me into a list of countries that requires that my friend's formal invitation be approved by the Romanian Foreign Ministry. This procedure has been completed and I sent my application for validation through their online visa portal on the 4th of Nov. It has been 3 weeks since and the status still says my file is being validated by the Consulate in New York.

Currently, I have a little more than 4 weeks for my flight and am nervous as I also have exams which might make it difficult for me to lodge my application if they take longer to perform this validation. I didn't think this stage would take that long.

I can't reach their consulate by email and when I tried calling, the prompt is in Romanian and there is no option to choose English.

So all I can ask is if anyone has any experience with applying for a Romanian Visa or has an idea of the timing of this procedure. Would appreciate any advice as well. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you already asked a Romanian speaking friend to call the embassy for you ?

Comment: Yeah, but when connecting to the visa office, it's just a message that provides the website one can apply on and then hangs up

Comment: Try contacting the embassy over the phone and speaking to a human (even outside the visa office), who could then transfer you to someone appropriate?

Comment: What happened in the end?

Comment: Hi Johnathan, So the consulate in New York is one of the most unprofessional places I've been to. Someone called me from their personal number from there and asked me to text them my green card to that number. I said I'm not comfortable with that and asked for an email address.

After emailing it, I replied by text and asked if this lady had any idea when I might receive the visa. She just told me not to bother her on her personal number, which is odd considering she got in touch with me using it.

Comment: It got to a point where I had about 5 days to go and still was not hearing anything from them. I had to call the Visa Center in Romania who were MUCH more professional and courteous about my situation and a few hours after speaking with them, I get a call from the NY consulate that my visa was approved and I can pickup my passport later that day.

Comment: After I arrived, the lady knew who I was, since she gave me some kinda stinkeye...I approach the window at my turn and the lady asks me "What do you want?". Said I arrived for my passport and she brought it, then threatens me in front of all these other people that she will call the FBI and tell them that I am threatening/harassing her.

Comment: what a story !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to OP from a Comment:

> Fortunately I did go over their heads and reported it to the visa center and was also encouraged to report this incident to the ministry of foreign affairs. In a few hours time, I got a call from the consulate that my visa was ready.

Comment: Fortunately I did go over their heads and reported it to the visa center and was also encouraged to report this incident to the ministry of foreign affairs. In a few hours time, I got a call from the consulate that my visa was ready.

Comment: @pnuts perhaps you could copy-paste your answer to this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78626/how-can-i-speed-up-the-processing-of-my-schengen-visa-at-the-portuguese-consulat