# How can I speed up the processing of my Schengen visa at the Portuguese consulate in Sydney?

Tags: visas, schengen, australia

I have lodged my visa application at the Portugal Consulate in Sydney. This was a last minute work plan and I need to fly out in five days (Friday evening/Saturday morning). What can I do to expedite the process? The Consulate here in Sydney is saying they will call when they have an update.

Answer (score 5):

As a non-EU citizen, I have applied and received a LOT of Schengen visas. In all honestly, you really have no control over their processing times, and really cannot do anything about it.

What you can usually do is to call them to tell them you have this issue and hope they'll act on it. Most of the embassies are kind enough to expedite the process for you. There is no guarantee though.