# France Tour - Schengen visa processing

Tags: visas, schengen, france, consulates

Is there any way to expedite the appointment for Schengen visa as we already booked the tour and the appointment is exactly 8 days prior to our departure date. We are not able to get an earlier date. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Appointment *where*? And did you read [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78626/how-can-i-speed-up-the-processing-of-my-schengen-visa-at-the-portuguese-consulat)?

Comment: Why did you book the tour before you know whether your visa will be approved?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions