# Romania visa application status- Sent for validation even after 27 days

Tags: visas, romania, application-status

I applied for a Romania business visa on 20th September 2019. and today is 16th October. Still I have not received an appointment to submit my documents to the embassy. I called embassy lots of times, but no proper reply. My journey date is on 15th November. What should I do, as even after 27 days, the status of my visa application still says "Sent for Validation"?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘no proper reply’?

Comment: mean no accepting calls.

Comment: Where are you applying from? Can you call the visa centre rather than the embassy itself? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59229/how-can-i-speed-up-the-processing-of-my-romanian-short-stay-visa-at-the-romanian?r=SearchResults Or enquire via a VFS website eg https://services.vfsglobal.com/india/Romania-index.html?

Comment: i am sorry what do you mean to call visa center?